# App Error:104 illegalArgumentException while running the Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, httpconnection

i have created one application which parsed the data and it will displyed in ListRow,for that i have created http connection as below.

```
enter code here
  public void run() {  
            System.out.println("Run Method called");


            HttpConnection Conn = null; 
            InputStream is = null;  
            try {      
                System.out.println("Before Connection");
                Conn = (HttpConnection)   Connector.open("MYURL;deviceside=true" );
                System.out.println("HTTP connection called");
                //conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("http://xyz.com/Verandah/RSS/RSSContent.aspx?CatId=4;deviceside=true");
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                    documentBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(true);
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
```

when i am running my application i am getting IllegalArgumentException.i have compiled my application and i found i am getting the above exception in this line **Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);**  am i doing wrong anything wrong while creating a connection? need your suggestion why i am getting exception at this line.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to open inputstream over httpconnection before passing it to parse() method.

In your code `is == null` at this line.

Add this line

```
is = Conn.getInputStream();
```

before passing `is` to parse() method.

Comment: but my problem is that i am not able to display that parsed data in ListRow.

Comment: Post another question with detailed explanation of your problem.